# NAT for second interface on private network

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding

I have the following configured for my two network interfaces.

eth1 10.93.90.1 (Production Network)
eth0 192.160.0.1 (Private Network/Labb Network)

I want to configure eth0 with NAT so I can communicate through eth1 onto the production network.

This is what I have tried:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
root@10.93.90.1 # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
root@10.93.90.1 # iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
root@10.93.90.1 # iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

But the node that is connected to the eth0 interface with the ip address 192.168.0.236 can't communicate with other nodes on the production network (10.0.0.0). It can however communicate with the host:

```
root@192.168.0.236 # ping 10.93.90.1
10.93.90.1 is alive!
```

But not any other hosts on the production network:

```
root@192.168.0.236 # ping 10.93.89.1
No response from 10.93.89.1
```

This works fine when I ping from the host itself:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # ping 10.93.89.1
PING 10.93.89.1 (10.93.89.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Am I missing something here? Or is this not possible to do with only using NAT?

## UPDATE 1

Routing table for host eth1 (10.93.90.1):

```
root@10.93.90.1 # route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use   Iface
default         fafne-vlan93.se 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0     eth1
10.93.0.0       *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Routing table for host eth0 (192.168.0.236)

```
root@192.168.0.236 # ip route list
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
default dev eth0  scope link  metric 99 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.221.167 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 99 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.236
```

## UPDATE 2

I have changed the following rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

To:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have also added the following rule to debug the ping:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix 'SNOOP_'
```

And here is the what got logged when I pinged from 192.168.0.236 to 10.93.89.1:

```
Apr  1 09:14:44 lnxchrispet kernel: [2415274.711664] SNOOP_IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 MAC=90:e2:ba:3c:87:c4:ac:cc:8e:37:47:a6:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.236 DST=10.93.89.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=9639 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=0 SEQ=0
Apr  1 09:14:44 lnxchrispet kernel: [2415274.711935] SNOOP_IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=7c:05:07:0e:36:03:70:54:d2:7c:45:be:08:00 SRC=10.93.89.1 DST=192.168.0.236 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=58826 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=0 SEQ=0
```

## UPDATE 3

This is all the loaded kernel modules for nat:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # lsmod |grep nat
iptable_nat            12928  1 
nf_nat                 18231  2 iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14078  3 nf_nat,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           52720  5 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_state
ip_tables              22042  2 iptable_nat,iptable_filter
x_tables               19118  6 ip_tables,iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_filter,xt_state,ipt_LOG
```

This module seems to be missing, is it relevant?

```
nf_nat_ipv4
```

I tried to load it but I dosen't seem to work:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # modprobe -v nf_nat_ipv4
root@10.93.90.1 # lsmod |grep nat
iptable_nat            12928  1 
nf_nat                 18231  2 iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14078  3 nf_nat,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           52720  5 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_state
ip_tables              22042  2 iptable_nat,iptable_filter
x_tables               19118  6 ip_tables,iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_filter,xt_state,ipt_LOG
```

## UPDATE 4

Something doens't seem right, the modules regarding NAT is missing:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # ls -l /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter
total 1076
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar  4 06:42 ipset
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar  4 06:42 ipvs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10416 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_amanda.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4336 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_broadcast.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14440 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_ftp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67360 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_h323.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12944 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_irc.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116096 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5552 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  32528 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_netlink.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14416 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_pptp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16672 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_proto_dccp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11912 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_proto_gre.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15192 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_proto_sctp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8992 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_proto_udplite.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10664 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_sane.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36480 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_sip.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6352 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_snmp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10240 Feb 29 18:10 nf_conntrack_tftp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11400 Feb 29 18:10 nfnetlink.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20120 Feb 29 18:10 nfnetlink_log.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18920 Feb 29 18:10 nfnetlink_queue.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4952 Feb 29 18:10 nf_tproxy_core.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44016 Feb 29 18:10 x_tables.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6904 Feb 29 18:10 xt_addrtype.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7688 Feb 29 18:10 xt_AUDIT.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4912 Feb 29 18:10 xt_CHECKSUM.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4384 Feb 29 18:10 xt_CLASSIFY.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5440 Feb 29 18:10 xt_cluster.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4144 Feb 29 18:10 xt_comment.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5480 Feb 29 18:10 xt_connbytes.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8776 Feb 29 18:10 xt_connlimit.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6560 Feb 29 18:10 xt_connmark.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6272 Feb 29 18:10 xt_CONNSECMARK.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7032 Feb 29 18:10 xt_conntrack.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4400 Feb 29 18:10 xt_cpu.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7232 Feb 29 18:10 xt_CT.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6376 Feb 29 18:10 xt_dccp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4352 Feb 29 18:10 xt_devgroup.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5448 Feb 29 18:10 xt_dscp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6176 Feb 29 18:10 xt_DSCP.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4704 Feb 29 18:10 xt_esp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17592 Feb 29 18:10 xt_hashlimit.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5280 Feb 29 18:10 xt_helper.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4472 Feb 29 18:10 xt_hl.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5896 Feb 29 18:10 xt_HL.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10888 Feb 29 18:10 xt_IDLETIMER.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4848 Feb 29 18:10 xt_iprange.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5672 Feb 29 18:10 xt_ipvs.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8168 Feb 29 18:10 xt_LED.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4456 Feb 29 18:10 xt_length.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6480 Feb 29 18:10 xt_limit.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4200 Feb 29 18:10 xt_mac.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4936 Feb 29 18:10 xt_mark.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5144 Feb 29 18:10 xt_multiport.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4536 Feb 29 18:10 xt_NFLOG.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6080 Feb 29 18:10 xt_NFQUEUE.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4792 Feb 29 18:10 xt_NOTRACK.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9536 Feb 29 18:10 xt_osf.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4272 Feb 29 18:10 xt_owner.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5192 Feb 29 18:10 xt_physdev.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4224 Feb 29 18:10 xt_pkttype.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5896 Feb 29 18:10 xt_policy.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5120 Feb 29 18:10 xt_quota.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5960 Feb 29 18:10 xt_rateest.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8968 Feb 29 18:10 xt_RATEEST.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4072 Feb 29 18:10 xt_realm.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20136 Feb 29 18:10 xt_recent.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5432 Feb 29 18:10 xt_sctp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6856 Feb 29 18:10 xt_SECMARK.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10432 Feb 29 18:10 xt_set.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8704 Feb 29 18:10 xt_socket.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5056 Feb 29 18:10 xt_state.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5232 Feb 29 18:10 xt_statistic.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5088 Feb 29 18:10 xt_string.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5024 Feb 29 18:10 xt_tcpmss.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8496 Feb 29 18:10 xt_TCPMSS.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5616 Feb 29 18:10 xt_TCPOPTSTRIP.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6376 Feb 29 18:10 xt_tcpudp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9216 Feb 29 18:10 xt_TEE.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6024 Feb 29 18:10 xt_time.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10848 Feb 29 18:10 xt_TPROXY.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4184 Feb 29 18:10 xt_TRACE.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5176 Feb 29 18:10 xt_u32.ko
```

The current kernel is 3.2.0-4-amd64 on Debian Wheezy system

```
root@10.93.90.1 # uname -r
3.2.0-4-amd64
root@10.93.90.1 # lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)
Release:    7.9
Codename:   wheezy
```

I will try to install the wheezy-backports kernel, 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64.

## UPDATE 5

I could load the correct modules after booting the wheezy-backports kernel 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64

```
root@10.93.90.1 # uname -r
3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64

root@10.93.90.1 # modprobe -v iptable_nat
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/x_tables.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_nat.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ipv4.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.ko

root@10.93.90.1 # lsmod |grep nat
iptable_nat            12646  1 
ip_tables              25967  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
nf_nat_ipv4            12912  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 18159  3 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           91426  6 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat,xt_state,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

Comment: What's the routing table for 236? And for 90.1?

Comment: I edited my question, see update 1.

Comment: Maybe `ip route list` works on 236? Its routes are important for seeing how its traffic gets routed. The NAT setup should be sufficient.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I edited my question again, please see update 1 again.

Comment: Hmm, looks all fine to me. Maybe add a rule (to 10.93.90.1) of  `iptables -I FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix 'SNOOP_'` temporarily, then attempt `ping -n 10.93.89.1` from 236, and then look at `/var/log/syslog` (or wherever the log ends up); or hmm again; maybe it's `10.93.89.1` that refuses to play nice(?)

Comment: Wait; what happens to return traffic? The last rule only forwards established TCP connection traffic, so e.g. ICMP traffic is not forwarded. Maybe you should blanket accept all packets for forwarding instead?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I have added additional information, please see update 2.

Comment: Right, it logs a ping handshake to-and-fro through `90.1`. So, if now `236` fails to see the ping response, I would believe there must be additional blocking rules in play. Either egress rules (mangle or nat tables) on `90.1` or rules on `236`.

Comment: Or, thinking about it more, maybe it needs the MASQUERADE rule for eth0 as well as eth1; I don't usually match on any interface for the masquerade rule. (hmm thinking more I'm getting less sure :-()

Comment: No, I don't think it should MASQUERADE to eth0; but the POSTROUTING chain needs to accept it, e.g. by accept policy, or else by a plain rule.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Thanks for you help. Please see update 3, it might be because a certain kernel module is not loaded.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I have fixed the problem, please see the answer. Thank you so much for you support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like the Debian Wheezy installation had a faulty kernel or NAT wasn't fully supported for it. It was missing one specific kernel module, `nf_nat_ipv4`. As can be seen here:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # lsmod |grep nat
iptable_nat            12928  1 
nf_nat                 18231  2 iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14078  3 nf_nat,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           52720  5 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_state
ip_tables              22042  2 iptable_nat,iptable_filter
x_tables               19118  6 ip_tables,iptable_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_filter,xt_state,ipt_LOG
```

#### Install 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 kernel

The default kernel for Debian Wheezy is `3.2.0-4-amd64`. So instead I installed the wheezy-backports kernel `3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64`.

```
root@10.93.90.1 # apt-get update
root@10.93.90.1 # apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-all-amd64

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 : Depends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.110~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

APT complained that the correct initramfs-tools package couldn't be installed as a dependency. So I hade to install that from wheezy-backports fist:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # apt-get -t wheezy-backports install initramfs-tools
```

I could then install the `3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64` kernel:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-all-amd64
```

I then reboot the system and continued with loading the NAT kernel moduels.

#### Loading the NAT kernel modules

I checked first if I had loaded the correct kernel:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # uname -r
3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
```

The system is currently running the backports kernel. I then proceeded with loading in the NAT kernel modules:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # modprobe -v iptable_nat
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/x_tables.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_nat.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ipv4.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.ko

root@10.93.90.1 # lsmod |grep nat
iptable_nat            12646  1 
ip_tables              25967  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
nf_nat_ipv4            12912  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 18159  3 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           91426  6 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat,xt_state,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

#### Testing NAT

I then configured ip forwarding and NAT again as it disappeared after boot:

```
root@10.93.90.1 # echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
root@10.93.90.1 # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then I tested to ping from 192.168.0.236 and it worked:

```
root@192.168.0.236 # ping 10.93.89.1
10.93.89.1 is alive!
```

#### Conclusions

The problem were that the correct NAT kernel modules couldn't be loaded and to fix this I had to install the kernel from the wheezy-backports and the load the NAT kernel modules.